# EDMX object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, edmx

I've used this code multiple times in my web app and for some reason this part keeps returning the error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
string username = "John";

using (TicketsEntities dbc = new TicketsEntities())
                {
                    var usr = from cs in dbc.Logins
                              where cs.FullName == username
                              select cs;

                    DataModel.Login lgn = usr.SingleOrDefault<DataModel.Login>();
                    string user = lgn.Email;
                    lbler.Text = user;
                }
```

There is only one entry in my db both with the name "John". I have tested for null but it keeps giving me the error on `string user = lgn.Email;`

Comment: Are you sure the case is same and also there are no spaces with `John` ? What is the data type of `FullName`, if its `char` then you may have empty spaces at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `lgn` is `null`, as `usr` maye have returned the default value `null` and assigned it to `lgn`.  Therefore you can check that `lgn` is not `null`:

```
if (lgn != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lgn.Email) {
   user = lgn.Email;
}

user = "User not found/Email has not been set";
```

Comment: Thanks. Although the string should never be null (since the username reads from AD Authentication) if I do that check it works. But if I remove the if statement, it throws the exception.